# Rails Join Model select joint columns

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, join

I have the following three models join-relationship

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contributions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :contributors, :through => :contributions
end

class Contributor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contributions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :books, :through => :contributions do
    def this_is_my_contribution(book, join_attrs) 
      Contribution.with_scope(:create => join_attrs) {self << book}
    end
  end
 end

class Contribution < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :contributor
end
```

Then after inserting records into the Contribution join model, I decided I want to do a query on this model to retrieve all the books and contributors names as a result query as in the following SQL equivalent

```
SELECT Contributions.*, Contributors.name, Books.name from Contributions 
INNER JOIN Contributors ON Contributors.id = Contributions.contributors_id 
INNER JOIN Books ON Books.id = Contributions.books_id
```

But in irb console, when I wrote this,

```
Contribution.joins(:contributor, :book).select("contributors.name, books.name,
  contributions.*")
```

I get the following output instead

```
 Contribution Load (0.8ms)  SELECT contributors.name, books.name, contributions.* FROM
 "contributions" INNER JOIN "contributors" ON "contributors"."id" =
 "contributions"."contributor_id" INNER 
 JOIN "books" ON "books"."id" = "contributions"."book_id"                                                                                                                                          
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Contribution id: 1, book_id: 1, contributor_id: 1, role: 
 "author", created_at: "2014-04-04 00:19:15", updated_at: "2014-04-04 00:19:15">, #
 <Contribution id: 2, book_id: 2, contributor_id: 2, role: "Author", created_at: "2014-
 04-05 06:20:34", updated_at: "2014-04-05 06:20:34">]>
```

I don't get any book's name and contributor's name based on the inner join foreign keys.

I couldn't understand how RAILS SQL statement be very wrong when that's what I intently want.

What is that I do fully comprehend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails models are mapped with the tables associated with it so after querying this model it returns models object which in this case is `Contribution` model which doesn't have other models attributes, to achieve what you want you need to write your query as

```
contributions = Contribution.joins(:contributor, :book).select("contributors.name
  as c_name, books.name as b_name, contributions.*")
```

returned result  will be array of Contributions and one could get book name from result by attribute b_name as

```
contributions.last.b_name
```

Note: depending on how you are going to use query results you have to choose between `joins` and `includes` you could read [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins?view=asciicast)

Comment: Thanks Sat's.  Sorry for my late reply.  
I haven't the chance to try the code above.  But after reading the link you provided above, it's becoming more crystal clear for me why it's necessary to such steps.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the response of query you wont see any books name, however if you do result[0].book.name, you will see the name of the book. It is just not visible in the result displayed but you can get it just by accessing it.

As sat's said, you can use include, so that it will not make extra query when you will access book table, however in join it will make extra DB call for each access to book table.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Though I must admit.  I wasn't really that comfortable to seeing how my code couldn't retrieve the results as I explicitly told it to do before you mentioned about using joins, selects and includes.  Will give it a go for my next project. Cheers!